# Apache camel get result as string

Tags: apache-camel

I have a simple application which use the camel-weather service. I can log the result in my console, but I want to save the result in a variable, like a String, so I can show it on a JLabel or something.

My route is:

```
from("weather:foo?location=Breda,Netherlands&appid=appid")
    .to("bean:outPutBean?method=printLn")
    .to("stream:out");
```

The outputBean does nothing more than a simple return at this moment. I want to create a JSON parser in that function.

```
public class OutputBean {
    public String printLn(String msg){
        return msg;
    }   
}
```

How can I save the result from the route in a variabele, so I can use the data on a later moment?

EDIT: 
My code looks like now:

```
camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {             
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("weather:foo?location="+ txtCity.getText() + "&mode=xml&units=metric&appid=appid")
        .setHeader("temperature", XPathBuilder.xpath("//temperature/@value", String.class))
        .to("bean:outPutBean?method=printLn")
        .to("stream:out");
    }
});
[HERE]

public class OutputBean {
    public String printLn(@Header("temperature")String temperature){
        return "Output: " + temperature;
    }
}
```

How can I use the temperature variabele on the [HERE] place?

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this.

1. Save whatever you want from your message to a header.

> ```
> from("weather:foo?location=Breda,Netherlands&appid=appid")
> .setHeader("myHeader", "myHeaderValue");    
> .to("bean:outPutBean?method=printLn")
> .to("stream:out");
> ```

You can get the value from either the input body or from somewhere else.

2. In your bean I would receive that header and save it and then do whatever you want.

> ```
> public class OutputBean {
>     public String printLn(@Header("myHeader")String header){
>         String value = header;
>         return value;
>     }
> ```

Comment: But how can I get the `value` in like `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, value);` ?

Comment: Just call the call that shows the dialog with the value as parameter. Or what do you mean? You have the value now just pass to where your dialog code will be.

Comment: Nice, I get the placename in my bean. But want I really need is this:

`camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
 @Override
 public void configure() throws Exception {
  from("weather:foo?location="+ txtCity.getText() + "&mode=xml&units=IMPERIAL&appid=appid")
  .setHeader("cityName", XPathBuilder.xpath("//city/@name", String.class))
  .to("bean:outPutBean?method=printLn")
  .to("stream:out");
  }
 });
   
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cityName);`

So I want to use the cityName after the route.

Comment: Then you need to "embedd" Camel into your normal java code and not use the context.addRoutes.. See here http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html    But yeah you need to use consumer/producer templates instead.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't get it for now, but I will try it later. I have added some extra code in my original post, so it is probably more readable.

Comment: But do you really need to do it after Camel is done? You could just insert your dialog code at the end of the route in your bean method?

Answer (score 0):

- Add a member variable to the class setting up the routes.
- Add an inline processor to the route
- In the processor get the string you want out of a header and store it in the variable